# p5.js canvas not visible

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

Hello to whoever is reading this

I have a problem with the below code, I can't seem to get the browser to display the canvas

JS Code:

sketch.js:

```
     var blob;

     function setup() {
        createCanvas(600, 600);
        blob = new Blob();
    }

    function draw() {
        background(0);
        blob.show();
    }
```

blob.js:

```
     function Blob() {
        this.pos = createVector(width / 2, height / 2);
        this.r = 64;
    }

    this.show = function() {
        fill(255);
        ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
    };
```

I first used a script-src attribute to link it as an external javascript file, which didn't work, then I tried to embed it inside an HTML document, but that didn't work either.

I also tried to change the browser, which failed to change the look of the webpage, which is still blank.

Then I tried to use the  element to display the canvas, which didn't work as well.

please help, I'm new to using the p5.js canvas

Answer (score 1):

The `this.show()` method should be **part of your `Blob()` object** like this

```
function Blob() {
  this.pos = createVector(width / 2, height / 2);
  this.r = 64;
  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
  }
};
```

[Here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/Q7vycAf8M)'s a working example.